# How to set value of HashMap in Model class

Tags: java, object, model, hashmap

I want to set the values of georgiaHash and marylandHash into Key_journal_model class. That model class only contains these 2 hashmaps and their getter setter methods.

I tried with object but thats not working.
demoHash is a method which returns hashmap.

```
public class Hash_function {

    public ArrayList<Key_journal_model> setHashmaps() {

    ArrayList<Key_journal_model> kjmList = new ArrayList<Key_journal_model>();

    HashMap<String, Float> georgiaHash = demoHash();            
    HashMap<String, Float> marylandHash = demoHash();

    Key_journal_model kjm = new Key_journal_model(georgiaHash,marylandHash);
    kjmList.add(kjm);

    return kjmList;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: When I am trying to access the model class's value again it is showing NULL.